# how can i echo out my video tag so that my videos will play at any device?

Tags: php, android, ios, html, video

i wanted to play my videos from the database using PHP and as i put my video tag in my echo statement video plays fine on a PC and laptop but when it comes to mobile android and IOS my player won't play the videos. this is the current code that i'm using

```
echo "<video loop autoplay width='1360' height='720'>
```

$name
    
";

i'd appreciate the help, i'm still new to programming so i'm trying my best to learn. thank you for your time

Comment: echo "<video loop autoplay width='1360' height='720'>
   <source src='$url' type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>$name</source>
    </video></a><br />";

Comment: what format is the video? can you share an example of the generated HTML

Comment: im gonna use android/ios device to view the videos on my website here's my current code <?php

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_upload");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{ $upload_id = $row['upload_id']; $name = $row['name'];
    $url = $row['url'];    
}
?>
    <video controls loop autoplay width="1360" height="720" id ="video">
   <source src="<?php echo "$url";?>" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
    <source src="<?php echo "$url";?>" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
    </video></a><br />